# Ajax working strangely

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am pretty new to making AJAX calls so forgive me if its a "dumb" question. Ill try to keep it short. This AJAX call is fired when a order comes through, and i want to notify that an order has come through by playing a short audio clip. Now whenever the audio is still playing, and i make an order, it works perfectly by refreshing the page and showing the new order + playing the music. However if the music has ended and i make an order after, the page does not refresh and nothing happens. If i need to clarify anything let me know!

```
var loop = 0;
var audio = new Audio("ex.mp3");

function getContent(timestamp) {
  var queryString = {
    'timestamp': timestamp
  };

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'Pizza.php',
    data: queryString,
    success: function(data) {
      if (loop == 1) {
        location.reload();
      }
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      audio.play();
      loop = 1;
      getContent(obj.timestamp);
    }
  });
}


$(function() {
  getContent();
});
```

Comment: erm `loop=1;` is right there

Comment: Ah yes. The data is of no importance to that page as its the timestamp of a textfile. Whenever an order is made the textfile changes, and so the timestamp changes. Is it necessary to use the data retrieved ? Also the if is not false all the time. Its only false whenever the audio has stopped playing (which i find strange).

Comment: So far i have come to the conclusion that the problem is not related at all with the audio-play. After changing the audio file to something much shorter, the orders still came through after the sound. But after a while (approximetly 20 seconds) it does not refresh.

Comment: Can we confirm that "data" is valid JSON?  If it does not resolve to an object, obj.timestamp will be an error, I think

Comment: Yes the data coming through is a number. And i have vertified that it does come through as intended.

Comment: After checking some more i have found the cause. "503 Backend fetch failed". Any ideas?

Comment: I think 503 means you're overloading the server.  It is unusual to put AJAX in a loop such as you're doing.  Usually it's more event driven; ie after a user input, the AJAX fires.  Is there a way you can approach this without a loop?  I would offer some advice but I'm having a hard time following what you're trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you're overloading the server with your loop. Essentially, you're sending a GET request over and over again, which is not a good idea.  Instead, you should be waiting for the user to make an order before sending the request.  Something like:

```
<button onclick="getContent()">SUBMIT ORDER</button>
```

And then remove the loop from your javascript to be more like:

```
...
success: function(data) {
   location.reload();
}
....
```

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, so I've left my answer a little vague, but I hope this gets you where you want to go.